# Select the rows that appear with the first unique value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For example, I now have:

```
C1      C2        C3
---------------------
A       1         8
B       2         7
A       2         6
B       3         3
C       4         3
```

I want to use the actor as the reference and choose the very first appearnce of C1, which means I want to select the first, second, the fifth rows.

How can I do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try posting some code showing what you have tried

Comment: How do you determine first appearance? Is there any column that gives you this information?

Comment: Without being able to see the query you are running, try using GROUP BY

Comment: Is it ordered by C2 or is that coincidence?

Comment: Was your question answered? If so, could you accept the answer, or else leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

I see three ways to do this, depending on whether you have a column that uniquely defines the order of the records, and which non-standard feature of MySql you are willing to use.

## 1. You have a column that uniquely defines the order

Let's say you have such a column and it is called **id**, then do this:

```
SELECT C1, C2, C3
FROM   T1
WHERE  id IN (
         SELECT Min(id)
         FROM   T1
         GROUP  BY C1);
```

## 2. You don't have a column that defines the order

In this case you rely completely on the order that MySql chooses for your query result.

There are two ways I can suggest to produce the desired result in this case, and since the first one is rather easy, the second one might not be that interesting after all.

### 2.1 Non-standard GROUP BY clause

MySql allows you to do a `GROUP BY` in combination with a `SELECT` list that contains non-grouped-by columns, which are not aggregated either. This is not allowed in standard SQL, and other engines refuse that kind of queries.

But it works in MySql:

```
SELECT C1, C2, C3
FROM   T1
GROUP BY C1;
```

### 2.2. MySql User Variables

In this case you could get the desired output with user variables. During the execution of the `SELECT` you can collect the C1 values you have visited in a variable, and then add as a `WHERE` condition that any next C1 value may not be present in this variable:

```
SELECT      C1, C2, C3
FROM        T1,
            (SELECT @done := '') as init
WHERE       NOT find_in_set(C1, @done)
AND         (@done := concat_ws(',', @done, C1)) is not null;
```

#### Output in all three cases:

```
C1      C2        C3
---------------------
A       1         8
B       2         7
C       4         3
```

[SQL fiddle of last solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d580/13).

#### Explanation

The order of evaluation is as follows:

- The `FROM` clause is evaluated, and there the engine will assign the empty string to the variable **@done**;
- For every record in the table, the `WHERE` clause is evaluated. If the first condition succeeds, it means that the value of **C1** was never visited before, and so the next condition is evaluated, which always yield true, but will as a side-effect add the value of **C1** to the string **@done**, separated by a comma;
- If the first condition of the `WHERE` fails, this means the value of **C1** was already visited before, and so the record will not be output. Also, because the first condition fails, the engine will not evaluate the second clause, as it already determined that the whole `WHERE` fails.